# Retrieve the full path to a folder on an intranet

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

How can we make from a jsp using a component-type browse, retrieve the full path to a folder on an intranet

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't do it.  Think about what a security hole it would be.